# Crashlytics, Parse: PFEncoder crashes

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We use Parse 1.7.5 in our current app. Crashlytics shows 146 Crashes because of 
PFEncoder.m line 92
-[PFEncoder encodeObject:]

These are the highlighted reports from Crashlytics:

```
6 HireMe    PFEncoder.m line 92 -[PFEncoder encodeObject:]
7 HireMe    PFCloudCodeController.m line 49 __80-[PFCloudCodeController callCloudCodeFunctionAsync:withParameters:sessionToken:]_block_invoke
8 Bolts     BFTask.m line 334 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2
```

Is this an error in the parse SDK? We've updated to the current Parse SDK but I just want to get sure it's not a fault of mine (and therefore hopefully resolved by Parse.com) before sending the app to App Review.

Comment: It probably depends on the object being processed.  Please show it.

Comment: unfortunately in the crash reports there's not a single hint what's being processed...

Comment: I believe that has a large bearing on this issue.  In the next release you should use Crashlytics to log what was being processed if this method throws an exception.

Comment: okay, think its like a needle in the haystack, but I guess you're right and that's the only thing I can do if this is not a common issue. Thanks